# Назывное предложение в сложном как ошибка

Tags: грамотная-речь, синтаксис, стилистика, стилистическая-сочетаемость, стилистическая-ошибка

Кто-нибудь может аргументированно, со ссылкой на источники объяснить, почему необходимо редактировать предложение "Новое оборудование, восстановили цех"? Клиент требует "назвать правило". Просматривала разделы о перечислительных отношениях, о точке с запятой в бессоюзном предложении - нашла нечто подобное только в описании места действия в пьесах: Старый дом; во дворе растет клен. Понимаю, что тут связь между предложениями слабее, чем в моем примере, но сформулировать правило затрудняюсь.

Comment: А контекст можно посмотреть? Уж больно странно выглядит такая фраза сама по себе. Может, отсюда и непреодолимое желание её переделать?!

Comment: Это рекламный буклет. История табачной фабрики. На странице под надписью "1976 год" описано, что случилось в этом году: "Новое оборудование, восстановили цех". Я исправила: "Завезли новое оборудование, восстановили цех". Клиент против.

Comment: Новое оборудование, восстановленный цех.

Comment: Предлагала - тоже не подошло. Добило то, что коллега-литредактор заверила начальство в том, что можно оставить как было. Но я-то знаю, что надо редактировать.

Comment: Можно связать несовместимые части тире, двоеточием или многоточием, если стиль позволяет.

Comment: Несовместимые части при перечислительной интонации отделяются точкой с запятой, но тут они более чем совместимые, потому и надо редактировать.

Comment: Может, интонация и перечислительная, да кроме интонации есть много чего другого.

Answer (score 3):

```
 Клиент требует "назвать правило".
```

Ну, и назовите: правило соблюдения правильной структуры  бессоюзного сложного предложения.

*Новое оборудование, восстановили цех.* - БСП

БСП - это

> один из двух основных структурных типов сложного предложения в русском
>   языке; выделяется по формальному критерию.
>
> Бессоюзие — это не просто отсутствие союза; это мобилизация других
>   средств связи — интонации, соотношения глагольных форм вида и времени
>   в предикативных частях, лексических показателей и пр.; это
>   использование строения простого предложения как структурного фактора в
>   сложном: Удилище согнулось в дугу, леска со свистом врезалась в воду
>   (К. Паустовский) — связь предикативных частей и выражение отношений
>   между ними выполняется посредством интонации перечисления, соотношения
>   видо-временных форм (последовательность), а также **параллельности
>   строения частей.** Ср.: Травой зарастают могилы — давностью зарастает
>   боль (М. Шолохов) — отношения сопоставления передаются интонацией (на
>   ее структуру указывает знак тире), параллельностью строения частей и
>   лексическим повтором (глагол зарастает в разных значениях, но в одной
>   форме).
>
> В сложном бессоюзном предложении выражаются общие для русской
>   синтаксической системы отношения равнозначности — неравнозначности,
>   которые в другом типе сложного предложения — союзном — передаются
>   сочинительными и подчинительными союзами: Розовато-лиловые тона песков
>   тускнели, (и) пустыня темнела (В. Вересаев); (Если) В рубле копейки
>   нет, так и не полон рубль (пословица); Пыль и запах парного молока
>   висели над деревенскими улицами (оттого что) — с лесных полян пригнали
>   коров (К. Паустовский).
>
> Источник: Л. Л. Касаткин, Е. В. Клобуков, Л.П.Крысин и др.. Русский
>   язык: учебник для студ. учреждений высш. проф. образования / [Л. Л.
>   Касаткин, Е. В. Клобуков, Л.П.Крысин и др.] ; под ред. Л.Л.Касаткина.
>   — 4-е изд., перераб. — М.: Издательский центр «Академия»,2011. — 784
>   с.. 2011

https://xn--80aaivjfyj3e.com/russkiy-yazyik-sovremennyiy/289-bessoyuznyie-slojnyie-173617.html

В предложенной структуре мы не видим параллельности строения частей - одно предложение номинативное, второе неопределённо-личное. В одном главный член подлежащее, во втором сказуемое - нет отношений перечисления или сопоставления, если это равнозначные отношения, а если неравнозначные - должны быть причинно-следственные отношения, их тоже нет.

Возможный вариант "номинативное предложение + односоставное с главным членом сказуемым" - это именительный темы (представления), но здесь этого тоже не наблюдается, следовательно, структура некорректна.

*Старый дом; во дворе растет клен.* - разнородность конструкций сглаживается точкой с запятой, которая делит предложение на две части, а всё вместе - описание декорации, места действия.

Comment: Вопросы остаются. Как объяснить правомерность такого: Раннее утро, только встает солнце? Если бы было "Раннее утро: только встает солнце", все было бы понятно. Но интонация перечислительная, и точки с запятой нет. Видимо, объяснение в большем смысловом единстве. И в "Старый дом; во дворе растет клен", и в "Раннее утро, только встает солнце" мы видим картину. А по сути "что-то происходит где-то", "что-то происходит тогда-то", то есть каждый пазл добавляет смысла. А в "Новое оборудование, восстановили цех" перечисляется последовательность событий. Но как сформулировать это по-научному?

Comment: Это максимально близко к правилу "Нарушение единства конструкций однородных частей в составе бессоюзного сложного предложения: «На картине изображено: раннее утро, только встает солнце". Тут есть главное предложение. А в моем случае оно подразумевается: все перечисленное произошло в одном году. Но формально однородных частей нет.

Comment: Да, это  "Нарушение единства конструкций однородных частей в составе бессоюзного сложного предложения" . И пример такой же. https://syntax.academic.ru/122/%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%  Покажите им этот пример на сайте, там написано: ошибка. Наш пример относится к БСП с однородными частями - там смысловое и грамматическое равноправие, если бы были причинно-следственные или временные отношения, тогда бы были возможны неоднородные части.

Comment: Есть перечисление. Перечисляется то, что случилось в 1976 году (см. комментарии к вопросу). То есть равносильно следующему: *1976 год — новое оборудование, восстановили завод.* Просто стилистика неудачна.

Answer (score -1):

В стилистике чаще приходится сопоставлять не "правильно/неправильно", а "удачно/неудачно".

*Новое оборудование, восстановили цех.* — Предложение нельзя назвать удачным. Грамматически оно правильно, так как **перечисляется** то, что произошло в 1976 году, но стилистически неудачно.

Предложение "Старый дом." подразумевает наличие — "вот старый дом". Так и — "вот новое оборудование". Ну и что? Это обрезанный контекст — не понятно, что именно имеется в виду. Оборудование уже установлено или только завезено и ожидает установки, или только планируется? Приходится догадываться. А это очень плохо. "Новое оборудование" — это номинативное предложение не является описанием того, что случилось в прошлом году. Имеется только объект события — оборудование, а само действие пропущено. Для описания случившегося нужен глагол. Фразы типа "старый дом" подходят только для описания внешнего вида (*есть старый дом*), но никак не событий.

Данный пример равносилен следующим:
*Новые документы, нужно оформить отчёт.

Новые продукты, нужно что-то приготовить.

Новая мебель, будем делать перестановку.

Новые животные, мы ходили в зоопарк.*
Таким предложениям не хватает слов по смыслу — а именно сказуемого. Грамотными такие предложения назвать никак нельзя.

Если восстановление цеха произошло за счёт установки нового оборудования, то необходимо поставить тире. И тогда у предложения появляется логика:
*Новое оборудование — восстановили цех.

Новое оборудование — цех восстановлен.*

Лучше всё-таки добавить глагол:
*Установлено новое оборудование, восстановили цех.* || Оптимальный вариант, отлично звучит.

Comment: Как вас понимать прикажете? Вы можете ответить на вопрос, почему надо редактировать?

Comment: @Горевант Потому что обрезанный контекст. Предложение стилистически неудачно и не звучит.

Comment: Да не мне, а в текст. Мне Людмила внятно объяснила: <<правило соблюдения правильной структуры бессоюзного сложного предложения>>. А про контекст - не понял вовсе. Что значит "обрезанный"?  Автор все пояснил.

Comment: @Горевант А в ответе так и написано, поэтому повторно именно вам. Но сам ответ расширю. Грамматически предложение правильное, но стилистика ужасна. Обрезанный контекст - не хватает слов для полноценного выражения мысли.

Comment: мне - не надо. Я уже принял решение.

Comment: Я и не спрашиваю. Я вам объясняю.

Comment: @Горевант В вашем первом комментарии два вопроса, ответы на которые имеются в самом ответе. || Ответ Людмилы хорош, но она не учла того, что между частями перечислительные отношения (события 1976 года). Тогда грамматика правильная ("правило соблюдения правильной структуры бессоюзного сложного предложения" здесь не нарушено!) и нужно разбираться со стилистикой, что я и делаю.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99539/discussion-between--and-oleedd).

Comment: @Горевант Давайте вы лучше удалите свои комментарии, вместо чата.

Comment: Ну знаете ли... Если бы вы прислушались к моему мнению, это имело бы смысл. А так...

Comment: @Горевант Я прислушался. Сейчас расширяю ответ. Он будет гораздо больше и с примерами. Не стоит сразу ставить дизлайк. Дизлайки стоит ставить только тогда, если ответ неправельный.